# Silverlight Binding TimePicker

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a data form with a timepicker and I cannot edit the value in the timepicker when I bind the value in XAML.  Here is the code for the xaml binding:

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="Start Date:" Width="325">
                            <sdk:DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Start Time:" Width="325">
                            <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="StartTime" PopupButtonMode="Hover" Value="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="End Date:" Width="325">
                            <sdk:DatePicker x:Name="EndDate" SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="End Time:" Width="325">
                            <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="EndTime" PopupButtonMode="Hover" Value="{Binding EndDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </toolkit:DataField>
```

What changes can I make to allow a user to change the value in the timepicker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at your debug output. Maybe the binding throws an exception.